# Programmatically change menu icon color in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've developed an App, where the user can change the theme. I have a navigation view, with a menu icon in Toolbar that is black.

I would like to change that icon, to have it white (on a black theme). I tried this code but it remained black:

```
myToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_menu_white_24dp); //ab=ActionBar
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The title becomes White, but the icon doesn't change.

Comment: setBackgroungTint(Color.WHITE) use this on your icon

Comment: How can i change that for the icon?

Comment: try like this myToolbar.setBackgroundTint()

Comment: I have only setBackgroundTintMode() and setBackgroundTintList()

Comment: if the them's parent is dark the system will change the icon color and text color to white automatically, you dont need to change its grammatically

Comment: checkout this link, if it meets your requirement
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-quick-tips-8-how-to-dynamically-tint-actionbar-menu-icons

Comment: 1. add a completely new icon with your favorite color   use this to tint 2.`Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_menu, null);
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.BLACK);
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.Add a completely new icon with your favorite color  `ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_new);`

2.Use this to tint

```
    Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_menu, null);
    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.WHITE);
    ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
```