# Change the color of MenuItem permanently from Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to change the color of a MenuItem from white to red permanently from fragment. In the fragmentselected (FragmentA) it changes color, but when I go to FragmentB it returns to white again. This is the code on fragmentselected

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    Drawable drawable=  menu.getItem(0).getIcon();
    drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

}
```

Comment: how you change at the first place? Show us the code

Comment: I just add my code. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the Text color of Menu item in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519277/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-menu-item-in-android)

Comment: Its not duplicated man, because I want my change to be saved from Fragment A to fragment B

Comment: Do you want to change only between two fragments?

Comment: Would you please provide some screenshorts that you want to achieve?

Comment: I cant provide screenshots. I just want that the change that it made, to be permanent. So even when I swipe the fragment, the final color to be red.

Comment: Are you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41317652/5167909

Comment: Thanks, it helped me

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
Drawable drawable=  menu.getItem(0).getIcon();
drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

to `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

**[UPDATE]**

Add one line in your theme

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>
```

Comment: Show me your onCreateOptionsMenu... edit your code up there

Comment: add under super.onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, inflater);... not above lmao

Comment: what do u mean by not working, any error, what did you see... elaborate

Comment: It just changes color to red only at the fragment that is selected. When I go to the other fragment, the color returns to white.

Comment: u mean in FragmentA to FragmentB?

Comment: Yes. If I do the change to FragmentA, it doesn't show to FragmentB

Comment: of course not showing..... you are setting Fragment A only not Fragment B, I will update my answer.

Comment: answer updated, just go to your theme xml and add it, mark as answer if it solve the problem

Comment: Still not working. I added your line. Should I make another change?

Comment: look at the "your_color" in the code, change the color there already?